# filter on collection giving different resuts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I have Laravel collection when I dump collection and when I filter collection and then dump it shows me different results. Can anybody tell me what is the difference between these two ??
The screenshot is attached below

[image]

[image]

I am filtering collection like this :

```
$non_uploaded_orders = $batch_orders->filter(function($item){
            return ($item->batch_id == null && $item->status != 'declined');
        });
```

Comment: show the code block you are talking about where you dump the collection and filter the collection then dump

Answer (score 1):

When you use `dump()`, it basically shows you the whole collection. Same collection when you use `dd()`.  However `dd()` shows the whole collection and stops execution of the code. `dump()` will show you the collection, but won't stop the execution of the code.

When you use `filter()`, filter will give you the filtered collection data which you give in the call back. If no callback is supplied, all entries of the collection that are equivalent to false will be removed.